# Variance of combination of Poisson and binomial distributions

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

The physical situation I am trying to understand is the detection of photons by a digital camera sensor. During an exposure, photons will hit a particular pixel and the number hitting the pixel can be represented by a Poisson distribution where both the mean and variance are given by $\lambda$.

If every photon was detected by the sensor then that would be the end of the problem, but in fact only a fraction of the photons are detected - the probability of detecting each photon can be given by $p$, which is usually referred to as the quantum efficiency (QE) of the sensor.

It seems immediately obvious that the mean number of photons that will be detected in this situation is given by $\lambda p$, but I cannot see how to work out the variance of this number.

If a fixed number, $n$, of photons hit the sensor then the variance would be given by the binomial distribution variance of $np(1-p)$, but how does the variance of this combine with the underlying variance due to the Poisson distribution of the number of photons hitting the sensor?

Comment: I am not sure if I answer correctly, but, I remember for a rather similar issue, having found a solution by composition of **moment generating functions (MGF)** for the Binomial  and the Poisson distribution resp.

Comment: Having now attacked the problem numerically (for the similar problem of composition of two binomial choices with probability $p_1$ and $p_2$), it looks like the result is very close to

$np_1(1-p_1)p_2^2 + np_1p_2(1-p_2)$
.
That is, the variance of the first binomial scaled down by $p_2^2$ added to the variance of the second binomial with an event count reduced by factor $p_1$. I couldn't prove it though. Will look into MGF to see if it leads me anywhere. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to be using single-trial Bernoulli random variables in your numerical attack. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, consider that you have two Poisson random variables.
Detected photons $D \sim \mathsf{Pois}(p\lambda)$ and Undetected photons
$U \sim \mathsf{Pois}((1-p)\lambda).$ Their sum is
$T = D + U \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda).$

Assuming independence, the variances compute properly:
$Var(T) = \lambda$ and $Var(D) + Var(U) = p\lambda = (1-p)\lambda = \lambda.$

---

There is a more general formulation, sometimes called 'random sum of random
variables', which you might want to google. Suppose there are $N \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=20)$ customers
a day each independently spending $X_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100, \sigma=15)$ dollars.

Then the total receipts in a day are $S = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i.$
In this situation $$E(S) = E(N)E(X) = \lambda\mu = 2000$$ and
$$V(S) = E(N)V(X) + V(N)[E(X)]^2 = \lambda\sigma^2 + \lambda\mu^2
= 20(225) + 20(10000) = 204500,$$ so $SD(S) = 452.2168.$

---

If you want to look at your photon problem according to this mechanism,
then the number of detected photons is $D = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i,$ where
$N \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$ and the $X_i \sim \mathsf{Bernoulli}(p)
\equiv \mathsf{Binom}(1, p).$ So that $E(D) = E(N)E(X) = \lambda p$
and $V(D) = E(N)V(X) + V(N)[E(X)]^2 = \lambda p(1-p) + \lambda p^2
= \lambda p$ as previously. Note particularly that the $X_i$ are *Bernoulli.*

---

Here is a simulation in R statistical software for a million pixels
each with $\lambda = 10$ and $p = 0.7.$

```
m = 10^6;  d = numeric(m)
lam = 10;  p = .7
for (i in 1:m) {
   n = rpois(1, lam)
   d[i] = rbinom(1, n, p) }
mean(d); var(d)
## 7.000906   # aprx E(D) = 7
## 7.003016   # aprx V(D) = 7
```

In the figure below, histogram bars show the simulated values of $D$ and
the red circles show the exact Poisson probabilities.

[image]

Comment: [+1] Remarkable answer.

Comment: Having seen the answer it is now also more intuitively obvious if there is a probability p of each Poisson event being counted then that leads to a Poisson distribution with mean and variance of $\lambda p$. Sadly this (correct) result means that my overall goal (to calculate the value of $p$ from noise and electron count measurements) is impossible since both the mean and variance of the number of photons detected are given by $\lambda p$. If the variance had a different form then I was hoping to end up with a set of two equations and two unknowns. Ah well :)

Comment: If you have approximations for $\lambda$ and $p$ based on prior experience or theory, it might be possible to use a Bayesian framework along with your data to sharpen these approximations.